# How do I count different types of characters in a text file

Tags: bash

I've seen different ways to search a text file for one character, but how would I count a-z and A-Z, spaces, digits, newlines, and special characters? I'm trying to do this in a bash script as well.

Comment: What's a "special character"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "special characters", but given a specific set of characters, I would count them like this:

```
tr -dc 'character-set' < file | wc -c
```

Ignoring "special characters", the rest of your requirements can be met this way:

```
tr -dc 'a-zA-Z 0-9\n' < file | wc -c
```

which will output the file minus all characters *not* meeting your requirements, and then pipe that to `wc -c`, which counts characters. All you have to do is update the character set description so it includes whatever other characters you need.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking to do, I was getting close but I couldn't get there! Thanks!

Comment: Cool cool, I'm brand new here and was looking how to do that because it very much answered my post.

Comment: Also by special characters I just mean anything that isn't letters, lumbers, spaces or new line characters.

Comment: @user3347022 If you read the `re_format` (OS X) or `regex(7)` (Linux) man pages, you'll see definitions for various standard character classes including `cntrl` and `print`. Those are a good start for identifying exactly the characters you want to include/exclude.